# What is the equivalent of .Max() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq, max

I was wondering how can we write a jquery statement to get the max value of a property of matched elements.

in LINQ we say something like this:

```
var maxHeight = list.Max(a=> a.Height);
```

what is the best way to do this in jquery?

as an example let's say we want to select the max numeric value of all :text elements inside a container:

```
var allInputs = $("#container :text");
// how to get the max of parseInt(item.val())?
```

of course having a loop over all elements is an option but I'm curious to know if there is a magic to do with jquery.

Regards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on all the conversation here and my search in the net we can say that (at this time) there is no robust built-in jquery way to calculate .max() and .min() of a property of elements matching a selector.

From what Igor suggested I came up with the following two jquery functions which you can add to your project if you need to use .max() and .min() functionalities over and over:

```
$.fn.max = function(selector) { 
    return Math.max.apply(null, this.map(function(index, el) { return selector.apply(el); }).get() ); 
}

$.fn.min = function(selector) { 
    return Math.min.apply(null, this.map(function(index, el) { return selector.apply(el); }).get() );
}

// Usage:

var maxWidth = $("a").max(function() {return $(this).width(); });
var minWidth = $("a").min(function() {return $(this).width(); });
```

See a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/NF7v7/3/

Answer (score 17):

One of the possible solutions is to use `map` function and then `Math.max` to the result:

```
var values = $.map($("input:text"), function(el, index) { return parseInt($(el).val()); });
var max = Math.max.apply(null, values);
```

If it is needed it might be written in one line.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WuVLr/1/

**UPDATE:**

Alternatively you can apply `map` in this way:

```
var values = $("input:text").map(function(index, el) { return parseInt($(el).val()); }).get();
```

Comment: Why `$.map()` and not `.map()`?

Comment: Added to answer, but it is not much shorter

Comment: If I'm reading [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) correctly, array-like objects (like `$('input:text')`) have to be converted into actual arrays before being passed into `$.map`. On the other hand `.map()` is specifically intended for jQuery objects. This implies that `.map()` is the better choice here...

Comment: As I understand they have to be converted in case when `length == 1`

Answer (score 0):

This could be a non-direct solution for that using an array:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var mySizes=new Array();
                $("input[type=text]").each(
                   function( intIndex ){
                      mySizes[intIndex] = $(this).val().length;
                   });
                var largest = mySizes.sort(function(a,b){return a - b}).slice(-1);
                alert("The maximun length is: " + largest);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="Test"id="1"/>
    <input type="text" value="Goodbye"id="2"/>
    <input type="text" value="Bye"id="3"/>
    <input type="text" value="Hello"id="4"/>
    <input type="text" value="Hello world!"id="5"/>
    <input type="text" value="Hi"id="6"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the open source project http://www.jinqjs.com
Using jinqJs you could do the following:

You could get the max by doing this:

```
var result = jinqJs().from([2,5,4,6,7,8,3]).orderBy([{sort: 'desc'}]).top(1).select();
```

or the min by doing this:

```
var result = jinqJs().from([2,5,4,6,7,8,3]).orderBy([{sort: 'desc'}]).bottom(1).select();
```